# Selecting last action from log table

Tags: mysql

I have some kind of log table which registers every interesting event that an agent has. Basically, if it's logged or busy or whatever.

With that said, imagine this:

```
    agent       event           dateTime
1   foo       logged        2012-03-01 14:23:36
2   foo       unlogged      2012-03-01 14:24:36
3   baz       logged        2012-03-01 14:25:36
4   bar       logged        2012-04-01 08:24:36
6   bar       unlogged      2012-04-01 08:25:36
7   foo       logged        2012-04-01 08:26:36
```

I want to retrieve just the ones that are "logged" so, in this example, it would be foo (id 7) and baz (id 3) (obsesive worker here...)

I've been thinking but didn't find the trick.

Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
**Updated once again to retrieve last status**

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT agent, 
 MAX(`dateTime`) as lastActionDt, 
 MAX(CASE WHEN `event`='logged' THEN `dateTime` END) as last_logged_in_event,
 MAX(CASE WHEN `event`='unlogged' THEN `dateTime` END) as last_logged_out_event 
 FROM table1 
 GROUP BY agent
 HAVING last_logged_out_event IS NULL OR last_logged_in_event>last_logged_out_event
) b ON
 (b.agent = a.agent AND b.lastActionDt = a.`dateTime`)
```

I assume it's impossible to have `unlogged` event without corresponding `logged`. If it's possible, then `HAVING` should look `HAVING  last_logged_in_event IS NOT NULL AND(last_logged_out_event IS NULL OR last_logged_in_event>last_logged_out_event)`.

Comment: I think the OP wants a list of currently logged in agents, not the latest login-date of each agent. But maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @ knittl : oops, you are right, it was actually me who misunderstood the question . thanks, fixing.

Comment: This is working like a charm thank you very much. I guess you learn something new every day

Comment: @a1ex07 what if I have more status but still want to filter down and retrieve the LAST status ONLY if it's logged?

Comment: Check updated version.  If I understood you right, it should return what you need

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM log l
  WHERE log.agent = l.agent
  AND l.event = 'unlogged'
  AND l.datetime > log.datetime
)
```

Comment: what if I have more status but still want to filter down and retrieve the LAST status ONLY if it's logged?

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( … WHERE l.event != 'logged' …)`?